# Check if JSON node is null

Tags: java, android, json

I'm returning some JSON from an api, and one of the child nodes of the root object is `item`.

I want to check whether this value at this node is null. Here's what I'm trying, which is currently throwing a `JSONException` when the node actually is null:

```
if (response.getJSONObject("item") != null) {

// do some things with the item node

} else {

// do something else

}
```

Logcat

```
07-22 19:26:00.500: W/System.err(1237): org.json.JSONException: Value null at item of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Note that the this `item` node isn't just a string value, but a child object. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, so if the node always exists, you can check for null using the .isNull() method.

```
if (!response.isNull("item")) {

// do some things with the item node

} else {

// do something else

}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. I wish they never included the `has()` method.

Comment: The method `has("tag")` is important for scenarios in which for one reason som expected "tag" is not returned(request from RestFull), by this method we can avoid exceptions!!!!

Answer (score 9):

To do a proper null check of a JsonNode field:

`JsonNode jsonNode = response.get("item");`

`if(jsonNode == null || jsonNode.isNull()) { }`

The item is either not present in response, or explicitly set to null .

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your response is from httpClient right? If so, you can just check the length of it.

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

String.valueOf(responseBody.length())
```

If you are getting anything should be greater than 0 I suppose :)

Answer (score -2):

First you can check if the key exists, using  method `has("")`;

```
if(response.has("item")) {

    if (response.getJSONObject("item") != null) {

        // do some things with the item node

    } else {

        // do something else

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that won't work, because the response always returns the "item" node, but it looks like this `"item":null` sometimes. Hence, it would bypass the first if statement and then throw the exception at the second if statement.

Comment: An exception will be thrown without you perform this call `response.getJSONObject ("Item")`, and the key 'item' does not exist!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the meaning of your last comment. The key `item` will always be present in the Json Object. It's just a matter of whether the value is real data or `null`.